# "AllowMultiple" attribute is showing different characteristics on different PCs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Here's my code :=

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

This line of code is working on my PC(config : Windows 7, .NET Framework 4). It is selecting multiple files in one go. 
But if I am trying this code in different PC (same config.), it is selecting only a single file on attempt of multiple files.

Comment: what browser on different machine you are using ? and what on yours ?

Comment: Multiple file uploads [do not work in IE9 or earlier](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0e72657-962f-4254-b95c-c47482401899/multiple-file-uploading-in-ie9-and-older-versions?forum=ieextensiondevelopment)

Comment: Iam using same browser (google chrome) on both PC..

Comment: And one more thing ..when iam selecting a file in fileupload,it is showing me the entire path instead of filename..